# How to export to CSV from sqlite3 on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sqlite, export, dump

How can I export data from an sqlite3 database in Objective-c? Can I issue a dump command at least? What options do I have for exporting?

Comment: This question is similar to yours: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512883/how-to-convert-data-to-csv-or-html-format

Comment: Umh... I am trying to avoid having to "reinvent the wheel" here by writing the thing at the lowest level... I was wondering if there might be some already known and tested way to do the export, something in the sense of the FMDB wrapper.

Comment: No.  There's not any way without using some 3rd-party library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look into how the .dump command is implemented by the sqlite shell, to see how you can accomplish the same thing. In particular take a look at the dump_callback function and also the actions taken when the word dump is seen by the shell

[Shell.c source code: dump_callback()](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/s?refs=dump_callback&project=/onnv)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any built-in method for dumping a SQLite database in [the sqlite api](http://sqlite.org/c3ref/funclist.html).  However, I imagine you could probably cook something up to find all tables and their schemas, then SELECT * FROM each one and export it as a text file manually.