# Creating csv files in ObjC

Tags: c++, iphone, c, objective-c, csv

Is it possible or any library available for creating .csv file in ObjC ?

Thanks

Comment: Probably because the asker is willing to consider using C or C++ libraries that may accomplish this task already. Remember that using C and C++ in Objective-C is supported, and easy.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1512883/how-to-convert-data-to-csv-or-html-format and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1159576/how-to-export-data-to-a-csv-file-with-iphone-sdk-3-0

Comment: C CSV Parser: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvparser C CSV Writer: http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccsvwriter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A CSV file is a text file of comma seperated values.

You could write an a routine that loops through values adding each one to a text file (or even add the values to a string?). After each field, add the ',' character. At the end of each row, add a new line. The first row can be the field titles.

E.g.

```
Year,Make,Model
1997,Ford,E350
2000,Mercury,Cougar
```

Here is a wikipedia [article that describes what CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) is. I hope it can help.

Answer (score 1):

CSV files are very simple.

If the data for each row is held in an array you could use `-NSArray componentsJoinedByString:`to create a row for the CSV file. You'd also have to escape the text but that's shouldn't be too tricky. All that's left is appending the row to a file.

You may also like to read [Writing a parser using NSScanner (a CSV parsing example)](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/11/writing-parser-using-nsscanner-csv.html), which explains how to read a CSV file.

Comment: While CSV can be simple, in general they are not. You must properly deal with column values containing the column separator (comma) and newlines.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [chcsvparser](https://github.com/davedelong/chcsvparser).

Answer (score 0):

NSArray has some functionality that can accomplish at least some of this (depending on whether or not you need to escape characters) pretty readily. Take a look at the componentsJoinedByString: method.

NSString has a partner method - componentsSeparatedByString: